# G- equivariant morphism of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let C be a site, let µ be a sheaf of groups on C. Can someone explain me what does a µ-equivariant morphism of sheaves on C means ?

I understand the definition of equivariant map between G-sets ( as given in wiki). Is it that in case of sheaves we simply use this definition considering the sheaves locally, or is there something more ?

Actually, I am trying to understand µ-torsor and while doing so I feel that perhaps I don't really understand the definition of µ-equivariant morphism of sheaves.

Can someone help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

$\mu$ can act on another sheaf (of sets) $\mathcal{F}$ via the usual axioms: a map $\mu\times\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}$ satisfying unitality and associativity. Then an equivariant morphism of sheaves equipped with such actions is just a morphism commuting with the action map. If $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are lucky enough to be even $\mu$-torsors, then an equivariant map is just an equivariant map of the underlying sheaves with a $\mu$-action.

Comment: Thanks! But using this definition , I am not being able to see how any G-equivariant map between trivial torsors, that is, f′:Y×G→Y×G over Y is going to be an isomorphism. All I have is this,  f'(y,g) = f'(y,e.g) = g.f'(y,e). ( where e is the group identity). How can I use this to show the isomorphism ? Please help.

Comment: Well, $f(y,e)$ is given by some $(y,g_y)$ since the $f$ is over $Y$. Then $f(y,g)=(y,gg_y)$ and you get an inverse $(y,g)\mapsto (y,gg_y^{-1}$.